# Me carga el listado del "select2" detrás de un segundo modal hecho con “BootstrapDialog”

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3, select2

Partiendo de [**esta respuesta**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/228842/no-me-sirve-el-buscador-de-un-select2-en-un-modal-hecho-con-bootstrapdialog/228848#228848), me daba solución para un [**select2**](https://select2.org/) en el primer modal, pero ahora que lo necesito en un segundo modal no carga el listado encima del modal, sino detrás del mismo.

Acá el demo del error del **select2** en el modal **jsfiddle.net**: [**enlace**](https://jsfiddle.net/3rowjxma/3/show).

Acá una imagen del error:
[image: error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes solucionarlo con `z-index` asi:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
      let modal_popup = verObservs_dialog();
        modal_popup.open();
        $(window).on('shown.bs.modal', function() { 
          $(".modal.bootstrap-dialog").removeAttr("tabindex");
        });
    });

    let impuesto = 18.00;

    function verObservs_dialog(){
        let dialog = new BootstrapDialog({
            size: BootstrapDialog.SIZE_SMALL,
            title: 'Prueba',
            message: function(dialogRef){
                dialogRef.getModalContent()[0].getElementsByClassName("modal-body")[0].setAttribute('class', 'panel-body');

                var form = $('<form/>',{
                    'id' : 'form_observs',
                    'role'  : 'form',
                    'class'  : 'form-horizontal'
                });
                let div;
                let label;
                let div_field;
                let field;

                let div_b = $('<div/>',{
                    'class' : 'form-group col-sm-12 col-xs-12',
                });
                    let label_b = $('<label/>',{
                        'class' : 'text-center col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12',
                        'text'    : 'Productos'
                    });
                    label_b.appendTo(div_b);

                    let div_into_li;
                    div = $('<ul/>',{
                        'class' : 'nav nav-tabs',
                        'role'  : 'tablist',
                    });
                        label = $('<li/>',{
                            'class' : 'active',
                        });
                            div_into_li = $('<a/>',{
                                'href'        : '#productos',
                                'role'        : 'tab',
                                'data-toggle' : 'tab',
                                'html'        : 'Productos',
                            });
                            div_into_li.appendTo(label);
                        label.appendTo(div);

                        label = $('<li/>',{
                            'class' : '',
                        });
                            div_into_li = $('<a/>',{
                                'href'        : '#categorias',
                                'role'        : 'tab',
                                'data-toggle' : 'tab',
                                'html'        : 'Categorias',
                            });
                            div_into_li.appendTo(label);
                        label.appendTo(div);
                    div.appendTo(div_b);

                    let div_content = $('<div/>',{
                        'class' : 'tab-content',
                    });
                        let label_content = $('<div/>',{
                            'class' : 'tab-pane fade active in', 
                            'style' : 'padding-top:5%;padding-bottom:5%;', 
                            'id'    : 'productos',
                        });
                            div = $('<div/>',{
                                'class' : 'form-group col-sm-12 col-xs-12',
                            });
                                label = $('<label/>',{
                                    'for' : 'categoria_producto',
                                    'class' : 'control-label col-sm-3 col-xs-12',
                                    'text'    : 'Categorias: '
                                });
                                label.appendTo(div);
                                div_field = $('<div/>',{
                                    'class' : 'col-sm-9 col-xs-12',
                                });
                                    let field_categoria_producto = $('<select/>',{
                                        'class' : 'form-control select2-select',
                                        'id' : 'categoria_producto',
                                        'name' : 'categoria_producto',
                                        'style' : 'width: 100%;',
                                    });
                                    field_categoria_producto.appendTo(div_field);
                                div_field.appendTo(div);
                            div.appendTo(label_content);

                            div = $('<div/>',{
                                'class': 'form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12',
                            });
                                label = $('<label/>',{
                                    'for' : 'producto',
                                    'class' : 'control-label col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3',
                                    'text'    : 'Producto(s): '
                                });
                                label.appendTo(div);
                                
                                div_field_min = $('<div/>',{
                                    'class' : 'col-xs-10 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6',
                                });
                                    let field_insumo = $('<select/>',{
                                        'class' : 'form-control',
                                        'id' : 'producto',
                                        'name' : 'producto',
                                        'style' : 'width: 100%;',
                                    });
                                    field_insumo.appendTo(div_field_min);
                                div_field_min.appendTo(div);
                                
                                div_field_min = $('<div/>',{
                                    'class' : 'col-xs-2 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3',
                                });
                                    field = $('<button/>',{
                                        class:'btn btn-info',
                                        'id' : 'producto_b',
                                        'name' : 'producto_b',
                                        'style' : 'width: 100%;',
                                    });
                                        span_icon = $('<span/>',{
                                            class: 'fas fa-plus',
                                        });
                                        span_icon.appendTo(field);
                                        span_text = $('<span/>',{
                                            class: 'hidden-xs',
                                            html: ' Agregar',
                                        });
                                        span_text.appendTo(field);
                                    field.appendTo(div_field_min);
                                div_field_min.appendTo(div);
                            div.appendTo(label_content);

                        label_content.appendTo(div_content);
                    div_content.appendTo(div_b);

                    let div_field_b = $('<div/>',{
                        'class' : 'col-sm-12 col-xs-12',
                    });

                        field_categoria_producto.select2({
                            placeholder: "Elija...",
                            allowClear: true,
                            data:categorias,
                            escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
                            templateResult: categorias_formatData,
                            templateSelection: categorias_formatDataSelection
                        }).on('select2:select', function (e) {
                            let datos = e.params.data.productos;
                            datos.sort((a,b) => a.text < b.text ? -1 : +(a.text > b.text));
                            field_insumo.empty();
                            field_insumo.select2({
                                placeholder: "Elija...",
                                allowClear: true,
                                data: datos,
                                escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
                                templateResult: proveedor_formatData,
                                templateSelection: proveedor_formatDataSelection,
                            }).on('select2:select', function (e) {
                                let datos = e.params;
                                console.log(datos);
                            });
                            function proveedor_formatData (data) {
                                if (data.loading) return data.text;
                                return data.text;
                            }
                            function proveedor_formatDataSelection (data) {
                                return data.text;
                            }
                            field_insumo.val(null).trigger("change");
                        }).on('select2:unselect', function (e) {
                            let datos = productos;
                            field_insumo.empty();
                            field_insumo.select2({
                                placeholder: "Elija...",
                                allowClear: true,
                                data: datos,
                                escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
                                templateResult: proveedor_formatData,
                                templateSelection: proveedor_formatDataSelection,
                            }).on('select2:select', function (e) {
                                let datos = e.params;
                            });
                            function proveedor_formatData (data) {
                                if (data.loading) return data.text;
                                return data.text;
                            }
                            function proveedor_formatDataSelection (data) {
                                return data.text;
                            }
                            field_insumo.val(null).trigger("change");
                        });
                        function categorias_formatData (data) {
                            if (data.loading) return data.text;
                            return data.text;
                        }
                        function categorias_formatDataSelection (data) {
                            return data.text;
                        }

                        field_insumo.select2({
                            placeholder: "Elija...",
                            allowClear: true,
                            data: productos,
                            escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
                            templateResult: proveedor_formatData,
                            templateSelection: proveedor_formatDataSelection,
                        }).on('select2:select', function (e) {
                        });
                        function proveedor_formatData (data) {
                            if (data.loading) return data.text;
                            return data.text;
                        }
                        function proveedor_formatDataSelection (data) {
                            return data.text;
                        }

                        field_insumo.val(null).trigger("change");
                        field_categoria_producto.val(null).trigger("change");

                        field.on('click', function(event) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                        });
                    div_field_b.appendTo(div_b);
                div_b.appendTo(form);

                return form;
            },
            buttons: 
            [{
                label: 'Cerrar',
                icon: 'fa fa-remove',
                action: function(dialogRef) {
                    dialogRef.close();
                }
            }],
            onshow: function(dialogRef){
            },
            onshown: function(dialogRef){
             trasladarModal('datos');
            },
            onhidden: function(dialogRef){
            }
        });
        return dialog;
    };
    
    var trasladarModal = function(datos){
        modal_trasladar = trasladar_dialog(datos);
        modal_trasladar.open();
        let cabezera = modal_trasladar.$modalHeader.find('.bootstrap-dialog-close-button');
        cabezera.empty();
        let span_icon = $('<span/>',{
            class: 'fa fa-times boton_close',
            style: 'color:white;'
        });
        span_icon.appendTo(cabezera);
        $(window).on('shown.bs.modal', function() { 
            $(".modal.bootstrap-dialog").removeAttr("tabindex");
        });
    }
    
  let modal_trasladar = null;
    var trasladarModal = function(datos){
        modal_trasladar = trasladar_dialog(datos);
        modal_trasladar.open();
        let cabezera = modal_trasladar.$modalHeader.find('.bootstrap-dialog-close-button');
        cabezera.empty();
        let span_icon = $('<span/>',{
            class: 'fa fa-times boton_close',
            style: 'color:white;'
        });
        span_icon.appendTo(cabezera);
        $(window).on('shown.bs.modal', function() { 
            $(".modal.bootstrap-dialog").removeAttr("tabindex");
        });
    }
    


function trasladar_dialog(data){
 let dialog = new BootstrapDialog({
  title: 'Trasladar',
  message: function(dialogRef){

   console.log('datos->', data);

   dialogRef.getModalContent()[0].getElementsByClassName("modal-body")[0].setAttribute('class', 'panel-body');
        dialogRef.getModalContent()[0].getElementsByClassName("modal-header")[0].setAttribute('class', 'modal_header_editar');

   var form = $('<form/>',{
    'id' : 'form_eliminar_item',
    'role'  : 'form',
    'class'  : 'form-horizontal'
   });
   let div;
   let label;
   let div_field;
   let field;
      
        div = $('<div/>',{
            'class' : 'form-group col-sm-12 col-xs-12',
        });
            label = $('<label/>',{
                'for' : 'categoria_producto',
                'class' : 'control-label col-sm-3 col-xs-12',
                'text'    : 'Categorias: '
            });
            label.appendTo(div);
            div_field = $('<div/>',{
                'class' : 'col-sm-9 col-xs-12',
            });
                let field_categoria_producto = $('<select/>',{
                    'class' : 'form-control select2-select',
                    'id' : 'categoria_producto',
                    'name' : 'categoria_producto',
                    'style' : 'width: 100%;',
                });
                field_categoria_producto.appendTo(div_field);
            div_field.appendTo(div);
        div.appendTo(form);

        div = $('<div/>',{
            'class': 'form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12',
        });
            label = $('<label/>',{
                'for' : 'producto',
                'class' : 'control-label col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3',
                'text'    : 'Producto(s): '
            });
            label.appendTo(div);
            
            div_field_min = $('<div/>',{
                'class' : 'col-xs-10 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6',
            });
                let field_insumo = $('<select/>',{
                    'class' : 'form-control',
                    'id' : 'producto',
                    'name' : 'producto',
                    'style' : 'width: 100%;',
                });
                field_insumo.appendTo(div_field_min);
            div_field_min.appendTo(div);
            
            div_field_min = $('<div/>',{
                'class' : 'col-xs-2 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3',
            });
                field = $('<button/>',{
                    class:'btn btn-info',
                    'id' : 'producto_b',
                    'name' : 'producto_b',
                    'style' : 'width: 100%;',
                });
                    span_icon = $('<span/>',{
                        class: 'fas fa-plus',
                    });
                    span_icon.appendTo(field);
                    span_text = $('<span/>',{
                        class: 'hidden-xs',
                        html: ' Agregar',
                    });
                    span_text.appendTo(field);
                field.appendTo(div_field_min);
            div_field_min.appendTo(div);
        div.appendTo(form);
        
      field_categoria_producto.select2({
        placeholder: "Elija...",
        allowClear: true,
        data:categorias,
        escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
        templateResult: categorias_formatData,
        templateSelection: categorias_formatDataSelection
      }).on('select2:select', function (e) {
        let datos = e.params.data.productos;
        datos.sort((a,b) => a.text < b.text ? -1 : +(a.text > b.text));
        field_insumo.empty();
        field_insumo.select2({
          placeholder: "Elija...",
          allowClear: true,
          data: datos,
          escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
          templateResult: proveedor_formatData,
          templateSelection: proveedor_formatDataSelection,
        }).on('select2:select', function (e) {
          let datos = e.params;
          console.log(datos);
        });
        function proveedor_formatData (data) {
          if (data.loading) return data.text;
          return data.text;
        }
        function proveedor_formatDataSelection (data) {
          return data.text;
        }
        field_insumo.val(null).trigger("change");
      }).on('select2:unselect', function (e) {
        let datos = productos;
        field_insumo.empty();
        field_insumo.select2({
          placeholder: "Elija...",
          allowClear: true,
          data: datos,
          escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
          templateResult: proveedor_formatData,
          templateSelection: proveedor_formatDataSelection,
        }).on('select2:select', function (e) {
          let datos = e.params;
        });
        function proveedor_formatData (data) {
          if (data.loading) return data.text;
          return data.text;
        }
        function proveedor_formatDataSelection (data) {
          return data.text;
        }
        field_insumo.val(null).trigger("change");
      });
      function categorias_formatData (data) {
        if (data.loading) return data.text;
        return data.text;
      }
      function categorias_formatDataSelection (data) {
        return data.text;
      }

      field_insumo.select2({
        placeholder: "Elija...",
        allowClear: true,
        data: productos,
        escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
        templateResult: proveedor_formatData,
        templateSelection: proveedor_formatDataSelection,
      }).on('select2:select', function (e) {
      });
      function proveedor_formatData (data) {
        if (data.loading) return data.text;
        return data.text;
      }
      function proveedor_formatDataSelection (data) {
        return data.text;
      }

      field_insumo.val(null).trigger("change");
      field_categoria_producto.val(null).trigger("change");

      field.on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        trasladarModal('datos');
      });

   return form;
  },
  //cssClass: 'login-dialog',
  buttons: 
  [{
   label: 'Cerrar',
   icon: 'fa fa-remove',
   action: function(dialogRef) {
    dialogRef.close();
   }
  }]
 });
 return dialog;
};

let productos = [
  {
    "id": 435,
    "text": "aaaa",
    "precio": "11.00",
    "observ": [
      {
        "id": 83,
        "descripcion": "Mucha azucar"
      },
      {
        "id": 85,
        "descripcion": "Con toppings"
      },
      {
        "id": 86,
        "descripcion": "Con Chocolate"
      },
      {
        "id": 87,
        "descripcion": "Con alfajores"
      },
      {
        "id": 88,
        "descripcion": "Con caramelos"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 275,
    "text": "Arroz con leche",
    "precio": "15.00",
    "observ": [
      {
        "id": 83,
        "descripcion": "Mucha azucar"
      },
      {
        "id": 85,
        "descripcion": "Con toppings"
      },
      {
        "id": 86,
        "descripcion": "Con Chocolate"
      },
      {
        "id": 87,
        "descripcion": "Con alfajores"
      },
      {
        "id": 88,
        "descripcion": "Con caramelos"
      }
    ]
  }
];

let categorias = [
      {
        "id": 67,
        "text": " Bebidas Calientes",
        "observ": [
          {
            "id": 120,
            "descripcion": "Sin sorbete"
          }
        ],
        "productos": [
          {
            "id": 410,
            "text": "Cafe",
            "precio": 4
          },
          {
            "id": 411,
            "text": "Te",
            "precio": 7
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 66,
        "text": " Bebidas Frias",
        "observ": [
          {
            "id": 84,
            "descripcion": "Bajo Azucar"
          }
        ],
        "productos": [
          {
            "id": 407,
            "text": "Frugos",
            "precio": 12
          },
          {
            "id": 412,
            "text": "Inka Cola 1L",
            "precio": 14
          },
          {
            "id": 413,
            "text": "Cola Inglesa 3L",
            "precio": 20
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 51,
        "text": " Postres",
        "observ": [
          {
            "id": 83,
            "descripcion": "Mucha azucar"
          },
          {
            "id": 85,
            "descripcion": "Con toppings"
          },
          {
            "id": 86,
            "descripcion": "Con Chocolate"
          },
          {
            "id": 87,
            "descripcion": "Con alfajores"
          },
          {
            "id": 88,
            "descripcion": "Con caramelos"
          }
        ],
        "productos": [
          {
            "id": 275,
            "text": "Arroz con leche",
            "precio": 15
          },
          {
            "id": 310,
            "text": "Mazamorra morada",
            "precio": 20
          },
          {
            "id": 311,
            "text": "Leche asada",
            "precio": 5
          },
          {
            "id": 312,
            "text": "Flan",
            "precio": 24
          },
          {
            "id": 313,
            "text": "Arroz zambito",
            "precio": 27
          },
          {
            "id": 314,
            "text": "Manzana acaramelada",
            "precio": 15
          },
          {
            "id": 435,
            "text": "aaaa",
            "precio": 11
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
```

```css
.select2-container--open .select2-dropdown {
  z-index: 1070;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-gfdkjb5BdAXd+lj+gudLWI+BXq4IuLW5IT+brZEZsLFm++aCMlF1V92rMkPaX4PP" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.35.4/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.35.4/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```